# Java Android - situate the ListView under all other

Tags: java, android, android-layout, listview, android-listview

i has a layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="4dp"
    android:paddingTop="4dp" >


<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/lineradapter"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="6dp">

    <FrameLayout 
    android:id="@+id/frameLayout1" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="6dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top|left"
        android:fontFamily="normal"
        android:paddingBottom="2dip"
        android:paddingTop="6dip"
        android:textColor="#525252"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="normal" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/date"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top|right"
        android:fontFamily="normal"
        android:paddingBottom="2dip"
        android:paddingTop="6dip"
        android:text="00:00"
        android:textColor="#999999"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="italic" />

    </FrameLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/desc"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="6dip"
        android:textColor="#acacac"
        android:textSize="16dp" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="#e7e7e7"
        android:paddingTop="6dp"
        android:paddingBottom="4dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

in this layout i want to position the ListView. At the end, so that you can first see what the top, and then scroll down to see ListView. How to do it? I probyval added before /RelativeLayout>

```
   <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/comentadapter"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp">

       <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="4dp"
        android:layout_gravity="top|center"/>

       <ListView
           android:id="@+id/commentList"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

   </LinearLayout>
```

But it is still located at the top.

Comment: Yes before `</RelativeLayout>`

Comment: but it is still on top

Comment: And I want it to be at the bottom

Answer (score 0):

Use this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="4dp"
android:paddingTop="4dp" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/lineradapter"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:layout_weight=".3"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frameLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="6dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top|left"
            android:fontFamily="normal"
            android:paddingBottom="2dip"
            android:paddingTop="6dip"
            android:textColor="#525252"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="normal" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/date"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top|right"
            android:fontFamily="normal"
            android:paddingBottom="2dip"
            android:paddingTop="6dip"
            android:text="00:00"
            android:textColor="#999999"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="italic" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/desc"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="6dip"
        android:textColor="#acacac"
        android:textSize="16dp" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="#e7e7e7"
        android:paddingBottom="4dp"
        android:paddingTop="6dp" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/comentadapter"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight=".7"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp" >

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top|center"
        android:paddingTop="4dp" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/commentList"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: m, my listview not visible.

Comment: Have you checked in device or emulator?

Comment: But is there any data in ListView? And are you able to see ProgressBar??

Comment: ListView visible when desc or image not big, but if image on the fullscreen - Listview not visible, because i can not to scroll down. I want make comments, in the top info about post, in the bottom user comments.

Comment: look at the picture: http://imageshack.com/a/img829/4408/h64n.jpg

In not big image, and listvisible, but i want 
to be able to scroll down

Answer (score 0):

Best way to show the listview scrollable with the whole layout you will have to create two layout

for top.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="4dp"
    android:paddingTop="4dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lineradapter"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top|left"
            android:paddingBottom="2dip"
            android:paddingTop="6dip"
            android:textColor="#525252"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="normal" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/date"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top|right"
            android:paddingBottom="2dip"
            android:paddingTop="6dip"
            android:text="00:00"
            android:textColor="#999999"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="italic" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/desc"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:paddingBottom="6dip"
            android:textColor="#acacac"
            android:textSize="16dp" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="#e7e7e7"
            android:paddingBottom="4dp"
            android:paddingTop="6dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top|center"
        android:paddingTop="4dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and create another layout for listview list.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="4dp"
    android:paddingTop="4dp" >
       <ListView
           android:id="@+id/commentList"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

and setcontentview as list.xml and inflate top.xml and add to listview as Header like

```
ListView list =(ListView)findViewById(R.id.commentList);
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View headerView =inflater.inflate(R.layout.top.xml, null);
        list.addHeaderView(headerView);
```

Comment: ///    
commentAdapter = new CommentAdapter(this, comments);
ListView commentList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.commentList);
View header = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.onclick, null);
commentList.addHeaderView(header);
commentList.setAdapter(commentAdapter);
   ////
App closed with error!

Comment: on your question you have just posted row layout  View headerView =inflater.inflate(R.layout.xxxx, null);
        list.addHeaderView(headerView); you have to create an layout for topview that having image and text like http://imagizer.imageshack.us/a/img829/4408/h64n.jpg and replace xxxx by topview layout